# moderncv: Letter footer in resume

Tags: moderncv

There are two types of footers in moderncv. The first one appears in CV ("resume foot" in moderncvfooti.sty), and the second one - in Cover Letter ("letter foot" in moderncvfooti.sty). I want to have a Cover Letter footer also on CV pages. How can I do this?

So, at the end I want the resume foot...
[image: CV footer]

...to be changed by letter foot in the given page:
[image: Cover Letter footer]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That was my fist idea. But adding this line into "resume foot definition" changes everything to the letter footer. I'd like to have an option to choose a footer for a given page. In fact, I need one page to be with resume foot while all others - with letter foot.

Comment: Ok I understand the question now....Hmm, let me see what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

By putting this line `\strut{\bfseries\upshape\@firstname~\@lastname}\\% the \strut is required to ensure the line is exactly \baselineskip tall` in the section resume foot definition just before the line `\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtofoot[]{\addresssymbol\@addressstreet}%`, I was able to get the desired output.
[image]

This modification must be done in the .sty file

Comment: From the 'deadly sins' of LaTeX (more details [here (l2tabu), 1.3](http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf): *Never modify LaTeX class files or packages directly!* At least copy the `.sty` file to your folder and save it under a *different* name. Better make a container class, or use `\renewcommand` to overwrite the relevant commands.